# How do i use string index to single out first letters in a multiple element list/or tuple

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

How would I create a function essentially to single out only the a specific character for each element of the provided string logic I'm looking for:

ex. in a list of elements like:

```
countries_and_capitals = (
    ['Afghanistan', 'Kabul'], ['Albania', 'Tirana (Tirane)'], ['Algeria', 'Algiers'], ['Andorra', 'Andorra la Vella'],
    ['Angola', 'Luanda'], ['Antigua and Barbuda', "Saint John's"], ['Argentina', 'Buenos Aires'],
    ['Armenia', 'Yerevan'])
```

How could i create a logic to only display the elements that have the same First Letter for both Capital And Country ex. Algeria, Algiers.

Comment: If you find any one of these Posts help you, can you upvote it and acknowledge your acceptance/appreciation?

Answer (score 2):

If only use the `First` letter to determine matching, it'll probably be too `loose` and select some more as the results. For example: **S**outh Korea - **S**eoul; or **B**elgium to **B**russels. *Not sure this is desirable?* even it meets the initial requirement.

So to make this function more adaptable - this just makes the `matching` criteria as one character as default, but can be changed to select more characters if that's desirable later.

```
def find_same_name(lst, matching=1):
    '''
    find all matching capitals with Coutries, minimum matching is One char.
    '''

    # list comprehension

    return [sub  for sub in lst      
                 if sub[0][:matching] == sub[1][:matching]] # can determine matched req.
```

Running it:

```
print(find_same_name(countries_and_capitals))
```

Output:

```
[['Algeria', 'Algiers'], ['Andorra', 'Andorra la Vella']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new_list = []

for sublist in countries_and_capitals:

    if sublist[0][0] == sublist[1][0]:

        new_list.append(sublist)
```

And you'll get:

```
new_list

[['Algeria', 'Algiers'], ['Andorra', 'Andorra la Vella']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can index the first character in a string using `[]` brackets

```py
string = "ABC"

print(string[0]) # Will print first character in the string
```